# Java Null Pointer Exceptions in while Loops

Tags: java, hash, nullpointerexception

Below is some code to delete a number from an array in a hash-table. It uses a quadratic function.  How do I avoid a null pointer exception in the while statement? Thanks!

```
public Integer[] quadDelete(Integer[] array, int k)
{
    int i =0;
        while(array[i]!=k && i<array.length){   //This causes a null pointer exception
            i = ( hashFunction(k) + 4*i + 7*i*i) % divideAmount;                
            if(array[i]==k)
            array[i]= null;                

        }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Can you give values of array[] that you are passing as argument?

Comment: also, you didn't ask about it, but there is another problem where you will get IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions because you do array[i] before checking if i < array.length, you should reorder the while loop check expression to do the i < array.length first.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `array[i]` is null first before the `array[i]!=k`. Also check whether `array` itself is null or not before entering the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `array` isn't `null`:

1. You aren't incrementing `i`, so if `array[i]==k`, then `array[i]` is being set to `null`. You're getting the a NPE the second time through the loop when it tries to unbox the value from an Integer.
2. You should check that `i` is in range **before** trying to access `array[i]`, not afterwards, in the while-loop test.

Comment: 1) The value of i is being changed in the first line of the while loop. It may not *always* change, but perhaps that is intentional. 2) That is correct, but that would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` rather than an NPE.

Comment: @MAK - the fact that it doesn't always change could well be part of the problem ... given that the code doesn't check for `null` before unboxing the array elements.

Comment: @MAK - You're right about point 2. I should have been clear that this was not the source of the NPE but was going to lead to trouble later if not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you are getting the NPE in the loop condition the only possible reason could be that the array object passed is null. Check if array is null before you check the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the code corrected to avoid exceptions:

```
public Integer[] quadDelete(Integer[] array, int k) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array.length && array[i] != null && array[i] != k) {
        i = (hashFunction(k) + 4 * i + 7 * i * i) % divideAmount;                
        if (i < array.length && array[i] != null && array[i] == k) {
            array[i] = null;                
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

But I don't think that this version of the code makes much sense anyway:

- When the `if` condition is true, you assign `null` to `array[i]` which makes the `while` condition false ... so the loop terminates.
- If we assume that `hashFunction` is a pure function of its argument `k`, then in some cases the recalculation of `i` will give the same value, and the loop won't terminate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `i` is supposed to be incremented somewhere in there.